# get category and sub category

Tags: entity-framework

[image]

I have a tbl_SBAem_event table and tbl_SBAem_PricePackages table. Every tbl_SBAem_event consists of one or more tbl_SBAem_PricePackages . I need to get the tbl_SBAem_event along with the corrresponding tbl_SBAem_PricePackages . I am using MVC3 and EF as ORM. Any one has a sample code for this?

Comment: Can you show us the **table structure** ? What tables do you have, what columns (name and datatype) are they? Do you have some sample data, and the desired result?

Comment: I've uploaded an image for you to have an idea.

Comment: And what did you try so far to get those results? Btw. mapping is here to fix those ugly database namings to normal .NET naming conventions.